# yeoman generator creating files in home directory

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I am using the yeoman angular generator `https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular#readme`. I am following the instructions to install using the command `npm install -g grunt-cli bower yo generator-karma generator-angular` and then created a directory inside which I run the command `yo angular myApp` but the files are generated inside the home directory i.e `~/` The only directory I see inside angular-app is only the `node_modules`. Please help me understand where I am going wrong and how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer after hours of searching on internet. The Gruntfile.js was in the home directory and it was referring to it. I deleted the file inside my home directory and all of it started working again. Here is the link, which might be useful if someone face the same issue - [Link](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/635)